# UITableViewCell overlaps the delete button in the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delete-row

As shown in the image below when I enable the edit mode for the tableview and click the (-) button the delete button is hidden behind the UITAbleViewCell.

Not sure what causing the issue as I have used same similar type of custom UITAbleVeiwCells and delete worked without any problem.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9lkj.jpg]

Can someone enlighten me where I'm going wrong and why cell behaves in peculiar way.

Comment: Try setting `cell.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Comment: nope that didn't help :(

Comment: Set the same property on cell.contentView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `cell.clipsToBounds = YES;` can resolve the issue. 
Also try using the `imageView.maskToBounds = YES;` 
I don't know if you are having the images locally or you are downloading it from server. It could happen that the image is not downloaded when the delete button is shown and when it's downloaded the image is shown up as per it's size (contentMode). That's why I think setting `imageView.masksToBounds` could resolve the issue.

Comment: This one did helped me to narrow down the issue. As you have guessed I had a view and all the labels and imageviews were added as subview to that view. This view had caused all the problem. I fixed the autolayout issues in the (removed all) in storyboard and set the clipstobounds for that view. Did the magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

decrease the width of the imageview or view whatever that you gives to the image....

Comment: You mean programatically? If I manually reduce the size then they won't look nice in the uitableview?

Comment: may be your width of imageview have been crossed the total width of cell

Comment: programetically or manually , but you have to fixed the x-co-ordinate of imageview and width of it like that it can't cross the width of a cell